# Cannot find module "ionic-native" - Trying out Facebook Native Authentication

Tags: ionic2

I am very new to Ionic 2 and have been breaking my head into trying out native Facebook login authentication, I have tried few approaches below, and got no where !

- When I tried `import {Facebook} from 'ionic-native'`; I get the
  "Cannot find module "ionic-native"" error, however I can access the
  login method by using this `Facebook.login(['email'])` in my code.
- When I tired `import {Facebook} from '@ionic-native/facebook';` [I have
  this installed using `npm install @ionic-native/facebook --latest --save`] , I am unable to access the login method and I get this error **Typescript Error Property 'login' does not exist on type 'typeof Facebook'.**

Can some one please direct me to a correct approach ??.

Pasted the error log below.

Runtime Error
Cannot find module "ionic-native"
Stack

> Error: Cannot find module "ionic-native" at Object.
>   (//localhost:8100/build/main.js:55660:7) at webpack_require
>   (//localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30) at Object.
>   (//localhost:8100/build/main.js:74450:77) at webpack_require
>   (//localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30) at Object.
>   (//localhost:8100/build/main.js:74188:73) at webpack_require
>   (//localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30) at Object.
>   (//localhost:8100/build/main.js:111876:70) at webpack_require
>   (//localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30) at
>   //localhost:8100/build/main.js:66:18 at
>   //localhost:8100/build/main.js:69:10
>
> Ionic Framework: 3.2.1 Ionic Native: ^3.5.0 Ionic App Scripts: 1.3.7
>   Angular Core: 4.1.0 Angular Compiler CLI: 4.1.0 Node: 6.10.2 OS
>   Platform: Windows 10 Navigator Platform: Win32 User Agent: Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36

Comment: Try npm install --save ionic-native@2.5.0 the ionic-native 3.5.0 works differently with each npm module for each plugin & @ionic-native/core. Look up docs

Comment: Hey thanks a ton... that works!! 
I used `import {Facebook} from 'ionic-native'` and the 2.5.1 version.

Answer (score 1):

As was [suggested by misha130 in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44089974/cannot-find-module-ionic-native-trying-out-facebook-native-authentication/44147828#comment75202257_44089974), I used

```
npm install --save ionic-native@2.5.1
```

and it worked.